# How can I search a python script for use of a class method before running?

Tags: python, introspection

I would like to be able to scan a python script for uses of a class method before running the script itself. For example, given the following script, get all uses of the "foo" method for class "A" and the arguments passed to the method

```
class A():
    def foo(self, val):
        return val + 1

class B():
    def foo(self, val):
        return val - 1

a = A()
b = B()

a_val = a.foo(1)
b_val = b.foo(1)
```

This is an overly simple example, but the goal here is to use something more than regex to search for a `foo()` pattern so that items like `b.foo(1)` are not returned. I've looked at the `ast` and `symtable` modules, but they don't seem to have the functionality I'm after. I realize this may be a difficult/impossible problem due to python being an interpreted language, but it seems like someone else had to have had this problem before

Comment: If the tasks you have in mind have to cover many cases of grammar and syntax, you can look into using tools like ANTLR or lex/yacc (?) BTW, there are ample Python grammars that can be used to generate whatever kind of tool you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with static code analysis because owner of the method is determined in runtime. For example I could add on to your example:

```
b = a
b.foo(0)
```

Here `b.foo(0)` is in fact an invocation of the class `A`'s `foo` method. And static code analysis can't know this, because this depends on runtime.

Which means that what you're asking for reduces to the halting problem. There is no way to do what you're asking for with a guaranteed (or even probabilistically more accurate than chance) correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but alas. You can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to inspect classes and functions on runtime:

```py
import inspect

class Foo:
    def bar(self, val):
        return val + 1

    def baz(self, number):
        return number

functions = inspect.getmembers(Foo(), predicate=inspect.ismethod)

for name, function in functions:
    sig = inspect.signature(function)
    print(f'Function "{name}" has a params {sig}')
```

Outputs:

```
Function "bar" has a params (val)
Function "baz" has a params (number)
```